# C# Adding an array to SQL CE database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

This may be to general of a question, and I apologize if it is. I'm trying to add data from an array to a SQL CE database. The array is 30 columns by up to 360 rows. I've found samples of different ways to do it, but are all inefficient on an array of the size I'm working with as they require each element of the array to be added individually. It seems logical to assume the is a wasy to add a full row of a the array as a row in the database, however I haven't found one yet. Does anyone have any input on how to do this?

Comment: Is it really slow?  I find inserting 360 rows to be a pretty fast operation, even one at a time.

Comment: Why are they "inefficient"? Have you profiled it? If you have arbitrary values for arbitrary columns you have to specify each value for each column for each row, there is no way to avoid that. Please post your array type and a sample database row.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add it to the SQL Server database instead of the CE database?

I'm assuming your CE database doesn't stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adapt this sample: http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com